# WM_CHAR hooked twice in some programs

Tags: winapi, keyboard-hook

I'm hooking WM_CHAR message using WH_GETMESSAGE hook. When I'm typing sth into firefox window or CodeBlocks editor, for every key typed I'm getting WM_CHAR twice. However, in chrome it's only one message. Why? And how can I deal with it?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(code >= HC_ACTION)
    {
        MSG* msg=(MSG *)lParam;
        if(msg->message==WM_CHAR)
        {
            MessageBox(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Why `>=` rather than `==`?  And why `MessageBox`? That's got to screw with things. Use `OutputDebugString` or some other benign logging mechanism

Comment: Replacing >= to == didn't change anything. MessageBox, because it's in dll and I can't easily use printf(). OutputDebugString doesn't work for me in CodeBlocks. But eh, seriously MessageBox is not the only thing which I'm checking. I use some variable that changes key typed if %2==0. And I'm incrementing it in every WM_CHAR received. While in Chrome, I must type two keys to get changed key, while in CB only one.

Comment: Never mind then, sounds like you know more than I do

Comment: It seems that Firefox/CodeBlocks call `PeekMessage(..., PM_NOREMOVE)` prior to actually removing the message from the queue. You can verify whether or not the message has been removed from the queue by evaluating `wParam` (see [`GetMsgProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981.aspx)). Depending on your needs, a [`WH_CALLWNDPROC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) might be more appropriate.

Comment: @IInspectable: looks like you should post this as an answer.